# How to rewrite laravel /public directory

Tags: url-rewriting, laravel

So by default the index.php is in the public directory. I want to rewrite the url so that abc.com/public/ becomes abc.com/ ??

I am very new to url rewriting ..

Answer (score 1):

**Laravel is designed to protect your application code.**

All the files except public folder should not have public access.So You should upload all other files just before public folder in your server.

**Still if you really want to change it:**
You can override the public folder using IOC container,
Ex:

```
App::bind('path.public', function() {
    return base_path().'/public_html';
});
```