# How to publish 2 Laravel sites next to each other on a multi-domain account?

Tags: multiple-domains, publishing, laravel

I've got one account at Hostpapa that I use to host multiple domains.
The public folder is /public_html and underneath are folders for each domain.
This results in

```
/public_html
---/ beta
---/site.com
---/site.nl
---/site.eu
```

The .com, .nl and .eu site will become exact copies of one another in the future but the beta site should point to another laravel instance and will have a different configuration.

I'm now trying to publish the beta version.
What I tried already:

1) At first I copied the entire laravel directory structure inside the /public_html/beta directory but this doesn't seem to be the way to go.
([How to rewrite laravel /public directory](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/79690/how-to-rewrite-laravel-public-directory))

2) My second attempt was to copy the contents of /laravel/public into the /public_html/beta folder and put the laravel folder inside the /public_html folder.  Like this:

```
/public_html
---/laravel
---/beta
---/site.com
---/site.nl
---/site.eu
```

This doesn't work as the directory structure is broken when using relative paths.

3) On my 3rd attempt I removed the laravel folder and copied it's contents directly in /public_html:

```
/public_html
---/app
---/bootstrap
---/config
---/database
---/public
---/resources
---/storage
---/tests
---/vendor
---/beta
---/site.com
---/site.nl
---/site.eu
```

This should fix the problem with the relative paths but now I get errors when using route names:

> Not Found The requested URL /routeName was not found on this server.

Even if this would work it would still bring me into trouble once I want to publish a production site next to my beta site.

Can somebody please point me in the right direction how to host 2 different laravel instances next to each other in one account?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem with this video : http://www.tisuchi.com/upload-laravel-projecy-cpanel/